# Continuous function - unsure of statement that lacks rigour

Tags: general-topology

I have the following statement in my Topology notes in a section on continuous functions -

> A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.
>
> Thus $f^{-1}(b)$ is finite.
>
> This shows that $f$ is continuous.

I know it is very light on rigour but I think it was just some throwaway fact the lecturer was stating. But can anyone recognise the gist of it/make sense of it and tell me what actual fact it is (attempting) to state?

Comment: It clearly doesn't show it is continuous. Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0\\ 0 & x =0.\end{cases}$$ For every $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f^{-1}(b)| = 1$, but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: how is $| f^{-1}(b)| = 1$ in your example?

Comment: @gnometorule: The $|\cdot |$ here denote cardinality, not absolute value.

Comment: @AsafKaraglia: lesson learned - don't participate before finishing your first coffee.

Comment: @sonicboom Did you happen to clear up what was actually meant?